# Adding View to Window Manager And Activity animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-windowmanager

I have added a button inside a window. I want to open activity by animating from left when user taps on that button.

**Problem:** For the first time when I change my activity and taps sliding animation dont works but second time while I am on that screen it works fine.

here is my code.

```
 if (basketFlagView == null)
        {
            windowManager = (WindowManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            basketFlagView = new BasketFlagView(activity);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getButtonParams(activity);
            windowManager.addView(basketFlagView, params);
        }
```